# Calculating a new lat/long co-ordinate by adding a distance to a starting co-ordinate?

Tags: r, gis, r-leaflet

I have an ascii grid of elevation data in 100M cells.  I have a lat/long for a starting point and I need to add up these 100m increments and get new lat/long co-ordinate to draw a colored box around.

Im using R and leaflet to draw a map with the elevation data under a series of markers. I want a nice color coded layer in the leaflet map to show elevation.

```
coords <- function(cells_east, cells_north) {
cells_east =1000
cells_north=1000
start_lat <- 48.922582
start_lng <- -101.497821
kmeast<-cells_east/10 #each cell 100 m
kmnorth<-cells_north/10 
#Latitude: 1 deg = 110.574 km
#Longitude: 1 deg = 111.320*cos(latitude) km
lat_east <- kmeast /110.574
lng_north <- kmnorth / (111.32 * cos(start_lat))
elevation <- dem$data[cells_east,cells_north] #elevation from ascii grid
ret <- c(lat_east+start_lat,lng_north+start_lng,elevation) #lat,lng,elev
}
```

I go the conversion functions off the web near the bottom, but it seems off. This example should be 100 km north and east from the south west starting point but when I punch the coords in google maps its in a way different spot. Not other side of the world wrong but clearly too inaccurate to be useful.

Comment: How inaccurate is it exactly? What kind of tolerance do you need? Your current approximation has only 10m precision (because you have 3 decimal places) and also will have additional error because you are assuming the Earth is a sphere, which it isn't. For many purposes this is fine but it sounds like it isn't for you

Comment: Yes, I agree with @Calum about the sources of uncertainty. The accuracy you have now seems pretty adequate just to draw a visualization of a colored box as long as the spatial extent of your map isn't that big

Comment: Its off by well over a 100km, even for a 100km test.  I understand the earth is a little squished but I had hope it would be close enough, or maybe theres a handy R library to do it for me, but cant find a preprepared solution. Its for the province of Manitoba, quite a large area Im afraid.

Comment: Just noticed that I think your function might not work as intended because `cos()` expects input in radians, not degrees. You should multiply your latitude by `pi/180` before taking the cosine and you should get a better result.

Comment: Yes! radians was the key! Much better now thanks.

Comment: Especially when getting into discussions about coordinates, spheroid earth-models, etc ... I prefer to use proven libraries for lat/lon-math. For this, I would use [`geosphere`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=geosphere)`::`[`destPoint`](https://rdrr.io/cran/geosphere/man/destPoint.html). (From a different viewpoint: I've tried to do it manually several times and made so many minor mistakes that adding a package-dependency on `geosphere` is *well worth* the investment. "Well, don't make those mistakes" is not a reasonable response :-)